# Swift 1.2 でtouchesMovedなどのtouchesの定義が変わっていてSet<NSObject>になっています。

Tags: swift

初めまして！
Swift 1.2 でtouchesMovedなどのtouchesの定義が変わっていて`Set<NSObject>`になっています。
このため、

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
let touch :UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
var touchPoint:CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
```

以前まではこう書けていたものが、

[image: swift1.2の場合]

画像のようなエラーになってしまい、touchに何を代入すればいいのか判りません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんな感じでいかがでしょうか？

```
if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch
```

参照元から抜粋

> **Error**: Set doesn't have the method anyObject()
>
> if let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch? {
>
> Now that you have a Swift Set that has typed objects you need to update your cast if you use one with the touches parameter.
>
> **Fix**: Use one of the new methods of Set like first or last, which return optional NSObject values
>
> There's a couple gotchas with this conversion. anyObject() was a method, but first is a property. Firstly, you'll call them differently (i.e: no parenthesis).
>
> Secondly You can't use as? UITouch and as UITouch? interchangeably anymore with Swift 1.2 (not sure if this is a bug or intended feature).
>
> if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {

参照元
http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2015/2/9/swift-12-fixes-and-breaks-a-few-things-you-should-be-excited

Comment: これですね！
このif文の中に全て収めることでエラーが消えました。
しかし無駄なif文を増やさないといけないのは辛いですねー

Comment: if文はOptional Bindingなのでnilが来ないことが保証されているなら let touch :UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch でもエラーは出ないですね（動くことも確認できました）。